# How to stop taking duplicate values of text field by using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, forms, validation

Code...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#add_variation").click(function(){
        var tag_val = $("#materials_input").val();

        // check if tag already added
        $("#adding_area_result").each(function() {
            if($(this).text() == tag_val){
                alert("same value again");
                return false;   
            }else{              
                // insert tags
        $("#adding_area_result").add('<li><span rel="variation_area" class="variation1_tag">'+tag_val+'</span><input type="hidden" name="variation1[]" id="variation1" value="'+tag_val+'" /></li>').appendTo("#adding_area_result");   
            }
        });


    });
});
</script>

</head>
<body>
<br>

<input type="text" maxlength="2048" class="text" name="materials_input" id="materials_input" />
<br>
<br>
<input type="button" value="Add" class="button-medium" id="add_variation" />
<div id="adding_area_result">

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: *Answer...*. **Edit:** Maybe you should write something about what you've tried etc., rather than just posting your code.

Comment: Please clarify "stop taking duplicate values of text field" and what you mean by that as that could mean many things.

Comment: What's the point of running an `each()` loop on a div with a unique ID? Why not just do `$("#adding_area_result").val()`?

Comment: the problem of my code is when i enter some content in text field and click add button twice it is inserting the duplicate value.

Comment: Well, your code is invalid for the `.add` as you cannot add duplicate elements by `id="variation1"` as that violates the HTML specification.

Comment: @tymeJV.. the reason was i want to take #adding_area_result li span text value

Comment: You can use a validation engine, and specify with field must be uniques. Take a look at here.

Comment: In the future, include a jsfiddle in addition to the code. Here's one I threw together for you: http://jsfiddle.net/b9chris/w8Mf3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below code. May be it will help you.

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#add_variation").click(function(){
        var tag_val = $("#materials_input").val();
        // check if tag already added

        var check_val ='';
        $(".adding_area_result li span").each(function() {
            if($(this).text() == tag_val){
                alert("same value again");
                check_val = '1';
            }
        });
            if(check_val == '')
            {
                $(".adding_area_result").append('<li><span rel="variation_area" class="variation1_tag">'+tag_val+'</span><input type="hidden" name="variation1[]" id="variation1" value="'+tag_val+'" /></li>');   
            }
            $("#materials_input").attr('value','');
    return true;


        });
    });
    </script>

    </head>
    <body>
    <br>

    <input type="text" maxlength="2048" class="text" name="materials_input" id="materials_input" value=""/>
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type="button" value="Add" class="button-medium" id="add_variation" />
    <ul class="adding_area_result">

    </ul>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: did you check your code? its not working.

Comment: Now please check.. Its working now. Little bit i did mistake

Comment: thank you so much Kishan..your code is working just what i actually want.Thank You..

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other issues pointed out by the commentors, you're adding the html to `#adding_area_result` twice. Both the `add` method and `appendTo` method add html to the selected element, so you only need one. You can just use the `append` method like so:

```
$("#adding_area_result").append('<li><span rel="variation_area" class="variation1_tag">'+tag_val+'</span><input type="hidden" name="variation1[]" id="variation1" value="'+tag_val+'" /></li>')
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason this is happening is that when you call .text(), it returns your text with white space around it caused by the surrounding HTML, causing the match to fail.  You can add a class to your inner span tag, and then use that to get the text for comparison.

Here's a JSFiddle demonstrating this:
http://jsfiddle.net/ZzdX9/

The specific change is:

```
if($(this).find(".tag").text() == tag_val)
{
    alert("same value again");
    return false;   
}
```

And then add the "tag" class to your injected HTML.

Comment: @mun..your code is working only first time if i enter the value 2nd time then it is not validating.

Answer (score 0):

Alter your code to insert a new id for the hidden element using the number of the current elements.  This is a pretty verbose example and you could refactor it to be more concise.

```
function addNewElement(newIndex, tag_val, element) {
    element.append('<li><span rel="variation_area" class="variation1_tag">' + tag_val + '</span><input type="hidden"  id="variation' + newIndex + '" value="' + tag_val + '" /></li>');
}
$("#add_variation").on('click', function () {
    var tag_val = $("#materials_input").val();
    var group = $(".adding_area_result");
    var newIndex = group.find('.variation1_tag').length ? group.find('.variation1_tag').length + 1 : 0;
    var isDuplicate = false;
    // add a new one
    if (newIndex) {
        group.find('.variation1_tag').each(function () {
            if ($(this).text() === tag_val) {
                isDuplicate = true;
            }
        });
    }
    if (!isDuplicate) {
        addNewElement(newIndex, tag_val, group);
    }
});
```

Comment: can you please give me the full working code?

Comment: I backed out that change, should work as it is.

Comment: no its not working properly, did you check?

Comment: My bad, I forgot to check each on for duplicates. See revised code.  Example: http://jsfiddle.net/ZdGYw/   - slightly better version here: http://jsfiddle.net/ZdGYw/1/